# Amazon EC2 DNS not answering globally

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

I am a developer and have virtually no experience configuring a server.
I configured Route 53 and my registrar to point to it.
Created 3 A record sets to point to my instance elastic ip.

When I dig my domain (or open it in lynx) it all works normal.
However, from the outside world nothing seems to happen.

I should mention that the elastic ip opens in the browser, no problem.
The domain is bheumovo.com.br

Any clues would be highly appreciated..
Thnx

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's mostly made its way around the world.

http://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/bheumovo.com.br

DNS changes can take time to show up on different networks because of DNS records' TTL (time-to-live).

Comment: I'm not sure why, but when I open it from inside, using lynx it shows me apache IT WORKS page. Which is the desired behaviour for now. From outside, I get nothing.

Comment: Define "nothing". Domain not found? Empty page?

Comment: chrome's This webpage is not available.

Comment: Chrome's "this webpage is not available" usually has more details at the bottom on the exact error.

Comment: The server at www.bheumovo.com.br can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

Comment: And `dig www.bheumovo.com.br` from the same machine works? With the www?

Comment: From the server it does. From my pc I got a servfail status

Comment: Does `whois bheumovo.com.br` show your domain's correct nameservers in the output? I'd note you said "When I dig my domain (or open it in lynx) it all works normal." which apparently isn't true...

Comment: Yes, whois show correct nameservers.
Dig and Lynx works normal from the server's command line. Not from my pc.